# Bootstrap 4 carousel link over writes all other links

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Has anyone else had this problem, I have three links colours

```
.custom-links > a, a:link, a:hover, a:visited {
    color: black;
}

.carousel-caption > a, a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:active {
    color: white;
}

.rss-links > a, a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:active {
    color: gray;
}

<div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>@slides.SlideTitle</h1>
                            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(slides.SlideUrl))
                            {
                                <p class="caption-link"><a href="@slides.SlideUrl">@slides.SlideSubTitle</a></p>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <p>@slides.SlideSubTitle</p>
                            }

                        </div>

<div class="rss-links">
                    <a href="@item.LinkToSource">Read More</a>
                </div>

<div class="col-md-6 link-padding custom-links">
                    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-block" href="@link.Url">@link.Name</a>
                </div>
```

Added other links

But no matter what I try, carousel-caption over writes the styles of my other 2 links.

Am I missing something here!!

Comment: where are the other 2 links ?

Comment: Added other 2 links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of problems with your code

This selector `>` is called the `direct descendant selector` which means that when you write `.carousel-caption > a` you are trying to select an `a` tag that is a direct descendant of the `.carousel-caption` which is not. In your HTML strucure i see that `a` is a direct descendant of the `p.caption-link`

Second, when you write `.carousel-caption > a, a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:active { color: white;}` it will select the direct descendant `a` ( which is not the case as i wrote before ) and all other `a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:active` from the ENTIRE document. Because you didn't put a selector before them also.

( for eg .selector a, .selector a:link, .selector a:hover etc. )

You just have to write something like

```css
.custom-links a {
  color: black;
}

.carousel-caption a{
  color: red; /* change to white */
}

.rss-links a{
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-caption">
  <p class="caption-link"><a href="#">this is the carousel link</a></p>
</div>
<div class="rss-links">
  <a href="@item.LinkToSource">Read More</a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 link-padding custom-links">
  <a class="btn btn-warning btn-block" href="@link.Url">@link.Name</a>
</div>
```